# Disappearing content when using sub-menu (menu and sub-menu fighting over targets)

Tags: html, css, menu, tabs, target

What I'm essentially trying to create is a website with multiple image galleries. There is a menu on the left that lets you select from the different galleries. After clicking a menu item, a gallery appears beside it on the right. Each gallery has a large image displayed with smaller thumbnails below it. Clicking a thumbnail changes the large image above it.

The problem I'm encountering is that both menus (the gallery selector on the left & the thumbnails/large image) are using the same method of hiding and displaying content. I achieve this through targets (with a display:block and display:none in the css classes).

As you can probably guess, because they are both hogging up that target, things aren't working as intended. When you click a thumbnail, it causes the larger menu target to change, and thus it disappears. Here is the code to illustrate the issue.

[JSFiddle (with the gallery inside the menu)](http://jsfiddle.net/knuxjr/Lq5nd5yq/)

[Another JSFiddle (separated to show them working independent of each other)](http://jsfiddle.net/knuxjr/j93yy2hy/)

What's the best way to go about creating a menu within a menu like this? Is there a way I can have 2 different ids targeted at the same time? (thus making sure the display:none doesn't go into effect for the menu while selecting thumbnails)

I'm trying to create this system with just HTML and CSS, so I'd prefer to make this work without javascript if possible. I've been racking my brain for hours though, so at this point I just want it to work. If that means adding JS to my site, I'm certainly open to any solutions. Thank you very much for your responses!

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#Menu1"><h3>Menu Item 1</h3></a>
    <a href="#Menu2"><h3>Menu Item 2</h3></a>
</div>   


<div class="tab-content" id="Menu1">
    <div class="main">
        <center><h3>This is Menu 1</h3></center>
        <div class="image-gallery">
            <div class="big-image">
                <img id="Red" src="http://www.venus.com/productimages/dept_swatches/crimson_sm.jpg" width="100"    height="50" />           
                <img id="Yellow" src="http://www.msubillings.edu/urelations/img/blockgold.gif" width="100" height="50" />   
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="image-gallery">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#Red"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8KZSfT5.gif" width="64" height="64" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Yellow"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pV56FNe.png" width="64" height="64" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="Menu2">
    <div class="main">
        <center><h3>Menu 2! Menu 2!</h3></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    background: #222224;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width:80%;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
    overflow:auto;
    }
.nav {
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    background: #a2bbc6;
    }

.tab-content{
    display: none;
    }

.tab-content:target {
    display: block;
    }


.image-gallery{
    width: 400px;
    padding:25px;
    border:solid 0px #c5c5c5;
    }

.image-gallery .big-image{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

.image-gallery .big-image img{
  display:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.image-gallery .big-image img:target {
    display:block;
    }

.image-gallery ul{
    margin-top:14px;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

.image-gallery li{
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    }

.image-gallery li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging and experimentation, I managed to come up with a solution to this. It's using Javascript (so I'm still open to a pure CSS solution if you have one).

I'm still working out the formatting, but the functionality now does exactly what I wanted it to do. If anyone else has a similar problem, check this out:

[JSFiddle (Working Menus)](http://jsfiddle.net/knuxjr/fc3w4s1n/)

Also came up with a slightly more complex version with sub-menus inside the outer menus (since that's my end goal with the site). It'll require some clever nesting to keep all of that information straight, but it's technically capable with this method:

[JSFiddle (With sub-menus)](http://jsfiddle.net/knuxjr/ah0tjh0z/)

Code for the regular menus below. 
HTML:

```
<div class="nav"><p id="toggle">
    <span style="color:blue">Menu 1</span>
    <span style="color:green"> Menu 2 </span>
    <span> Menu 3 (blank) </span>
</p></div>   

<div id="left">
    <div class="main">
        <center><h3>This is Menu 1</h3></center>
        <div class="image-gallery">
            <div class="big-image">
                <img id="Red" src="http://www.venus.com/productimages/dept_swatches/crimson_sm.jpg" width="100"    height="50" />           
                <img id="Yellow" src="http://www.msubillings.edu/urelations/img/blockgold.gif" width="100" height="50" />   
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="image-gallery">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#Red"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8KZSfT5.gif" width="64" height="64" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Yellow"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pV56FNe.png" width="64" height="64" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>  
</div>
<div id="right"> 
    <div class="main">
        <center><h3>Menu 2! Menu 2!</h3></center>
    </div>  
</div>
<div id="far"> There's nothing here yet </div>
```

CSS:

```
#right { display:none; }
#far { display:none; }

.main {
    background: #222224;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width:80%;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
    overflow:auto;
    }
.nav {
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    background: #a2bbc6;
    }

.tab-content{
    display: none;
    }

.tab-content:target {
    display: block;
    }


.image-gallery{
    width: 400px;
    padding:25px;
    border:solid 0px #c5c5c5;
    }

.image-gallery .big-image{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

.image-gallery .big-image img{
  display:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.image-gallery .big-image img:target {
    display:block;
    }

.image-gallery ul{
    margin-top:14px;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

.image-gallery li{
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    }

.image-gallery li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$('#toggle > span').click(function() {
    var ix = $(this).index();

    $('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
    $('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
    $('#far').toggle( ix === 2 );
});
```

Hope this helps someone else out!